# J/Connector fails to connect to Sphinx server via SphinxQL

Tags: java, jdbc, sphinx

I have a server running the latest version of Sphinx (2.0.1-id64-beta) and am trying to access its SphinxQL interface via a Java application using the latest J/Connector JDBC driver (5.1.18). Whenever a connection is attempted to be established the process will block indefinitely on a socket read. The call stack looks like the following:

(StackExchange informs me to that I am not permitted to post images directly due to my reputation level.)

Image: http://dunkelhaft.dyndns-server.com/tmp/callstack.png

It looks like the JDBC driver is waiting for the Sphinx server to supply it with some message that never arrives. It's worth noting that if I use something like the MySQL command-line client or Sequel Pro or a simple PHP script, the MySQL interface works without issue, leading me to suspect that the issue is some sort of protocol discrepancy between the Sphinx server and the JDBC protocol.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

you're not the only one with that problem. i don't have a direct solution, just some dirty workarounds to get things working - look [here](http://kudzia.eu/b/2012/01/new-sphinx-new-connectorj-headaches/) [in short - you'll have to use older connector/j and will need to make small change in the sphinx 2.0.3 code]. there's also a bug report to the sphinx devs: [#959](http://sphinxsearch.com/bugs/view.php?id=959).

edit. it seems that adding *mysql_version_string = 5.0.37* to the sphinx.conf [should solve the problem](http://sphinxsearch.com/bugs/view.php?id=959#c2534).